# jOOQ - array of select query

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jooq

Does jOOQ support array of select query? I want something like the following:

```
select table.*, array(select another_table.id from another_table where ...)
from   table;
```

I tried experimenting with `DSL.array(context.select(...).asField())` but this generates `array[(select ...)]` instead of `array(select(...))`.

Answer (score 7):

I should have done:

```
PostgresDSL.array(context.select(...))
```

Note that we are using `PostgresDSL` instead of the generic `DSL` and not applying `.asField()` to the select, to inline the inner select query into the outer query.